# Configuring PostgreSQL Logging for stored procedures and functions

Tags: postgresql

We are in the process of setting up a process to read log files and generate long-running query reports in PostgreSQL. However, we are looking for a configuration setting that allows us to track only stored procedure or function calls, excluding unnecessary DDL creation logs. The current configuration settings we have are:

```
log_statement = All
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
```

While these settings provide the desired log data, they generate a significant amount of logs impacting performance and storage. Is there a specific configuration setting or approach that can help us reduce the log files and retain only the necessary data for stored procedures and functions?

We appreciate any insights or recommendations on optimizing PostgreSQL logging for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

My first impulse was to get a superuser to set a parameter on your functions, so that only your functions are logged:

```
ALTER FUNCTION logme() SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;
```

But that will fail when the function is called by a non-superuser:

```
SELECT logme();
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_duration_statement"
```

You could work around that by making all your functions `SECURITY DEFINER` and have them be owned by a superuser, but that's certainly not desirable for security reasons.

The best I can come up with is to add explicit instrumentation to each of your functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc(...) RETURNS ...
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   tstart timestamp with time zone := clock_timestamp();
   ...
BEGIN
   ...
   /* either log the duration */
   RAISE LOG 'called function somefunc(): duration %', clock_timestamp() - tstart;
   /* or write it to a table */
   INSERT INTO logtab (funcname, start_time, duration)
   VALUES ('somefunc', tstart, clock_timestamp() - tstart);

   RETURN ...;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for your answer. this will make changes in all functions. Is there any other way postgres itself log function and procedure call along with parameter.

Comment: Do you think that if I knew a better way, I would have deliberately hidden it from you?